# Debian apt-get remove firefox-esr forces installation of chromium?

Tags: debian, apt-get

Why am I forced to have a browser installed? Is there a way around this?

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/ This question is off-topic on SO.

Answer (score 1):

Run the following command to find out which package wants you to have a browser installed.

```
apt-cache --installed rdepends firefox-esr
```